# KeyChain.getPrivateKey(Context,String) on Android 4.1?

Tags: android, security, keychain, private-key, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I read that there is problem with method KeyChain.getPrivateKey(Context,String) on Android 4.1 although on older versions it works. Does anybody has solution how to get private key on JellyBean?

Saw this [Using Android 4.1 Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261774/using-android-4-1-keychain) , but somehow could not get to work with my case.

Code that does not work on 4.1, but works great on older versions.

```
PrivateKey pk;
try {
    pk = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(context,string);
    byte[] pkByte = pk.getEncoded();
    pkBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(pkByte, Base64.NO_WRAP));
}
```

Edited: Found out that if I do not change certificate alias(default hex-hex-hex) when adding it, then getPrivateKey returns null, but when I change alias to, for example, aaa method returns something, but still not the correct privatekey. (for example, returned private key with primeP =null primeQ =null. On Android 4.0.4 primeP and primeQ are not null values)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume a `PrivateKey` can be encoded. If a `PrivateKey` returns `null` for `getEncoded()`, then it just doesn't support encoding. See the [documentation for Key.getEncoded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29).

In JellyBean, the private keys returned via `KeyChain` are never in the process. Any operation performed on them are actually done in another process because the actual key matter may be stored in a hardware security module of some sort. You may still call [`java.security.Signature`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Signature.html) APIs with this key.

Comment: getPrivateKey returns different value on JB than on different verions. The main thing I need is to get private key as String value. Is it possible on JB?